# "sudo apt update" gives erros and Ign: on my Debian. "The repository ... does not have a Release file". ubuntu.com found in update paths

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, source, vps

Something happened 2 my Debian release and I don't know how that happened.
I was not editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` .
I run Vultr VPS.

My problem looks like this:

```
my_login@debian:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://apprepo.vultr.com/debian universal InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-updates InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-backports InRelease
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Hit:10 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bullseye InRelease
Hit:11 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org tor-experimental-bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bullseye-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I was installing `tor` to operate `tor` middle relay.
I was doing all that's written [here](https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/).
I've created a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` named `tor.list`. And I've added the following entries:

- deb     [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bullseye main
- deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org bullseye main

But I was not editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` . 100% sure I wasn't touching it.

I have this VPS with Vultr. Do they control the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` ??
Like, Can they change this file while I'm rebooting my VPS??  Using this thing called `cloud-init` ??

```
my_login@debian:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep cloud-init
cloud-init                                      install
```

Because I was not editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and it's changed. But sure as hell I was restarting my server today 8 or 9 times.

And why everywhere is written `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` or
`http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. I have Debian Bullseye release.

```
my_login@debian:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Comment: just remove those ubuntu lines from your sources